# vs code copilot icon gone

Tags: visual-studio-code, github-copilot

I can't find the github copilot icon for vs code

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the GitHub Copilot extension and reloaded the window i closed the vscode with taskmanger and restarted it and i cant get it to work.

Comment: If you're talking about the left bar, then try right clicking and seeing if the item in the context menu there to display the copliot icon is unchecked. If it is, click it to make it checked again. Does that solve your problem?

Comment: No, it does not it's not there anymore but thanks for trying to help

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Hard-reloading VSCode doesn't make it appear again. There's nothing in the VSCode Output for Github Copilot.

Comment: @EdmundoSantos what if you run `View: Reset View Locations` in the command palette?

Comment: I downgraded the extension to a version released 2 weeks ago and it started working again.

Comment: if you go back to the latest version, do you get any useful info in the Output panel? (View > Output > various output channels)

Comment: Same problem. I clicked some option form the copilot icon in the status bar, and now icon is not showing in status bar but copilot is working. Help!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. Wasn't able to find any direct solutions on internet. Finally figured out on how to display the icon of Copilot in the VS Code Status Bar. I had mistakenly turned Copilot status off.

To fix the problem, right click on the VS Code Status Bar. A window will pop up with some options:

[image]

Now simply click on the Copilot status option and the tick means you have activated it. After that the icon will be available in the status bar.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This only applies to Organizations, but the fix for me was to enable 'Copilot Chat in the IDE' under Copilot->Policies and features

[https://github.com/organizations/{org}/settings/copilot/policies](https://github.com/organizations/%7Borg%7D/settings/copilot/policies)

[image: copilot policies]

Answer (score -1):

okay just simply go under the bottom panel and then right click please make sure copilot status is checked that is it
[checkthis image for ref](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxwYS.png)

Comment: read the comments. I already asked about this and they said it doesn't even show up there.